# Region put() versus putAll() in gemfire

Tags: java, gemfire

Is it a good idea to use putAll() on a gemfire region as opposed to using a put()?
Are there any evidences of performance benefits? I am nevertheless planning to do a performance test just wanted to know if someone has done it already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, .putAll() is a way to very high throughput from client to server. You are essentially removing the network latency of repeated trips from client to server.

There are ways to make throughput even higher but putAll() is an ingredient of even the higher way.

Comment: In addition to the performance concerns, is PutAll transactional, either all updates committed or non?